# TCP Sweep , Security warning ?

Tags: linux, centos, tcp

I've just recevie an email from my hosting company :

" Hello from AT&T Hosting and Applications Services.  I am a Security Engineer
here trying to track down a security incident that appears to have
originated from your network on May 03, 2011.  Please investigate a TCP
sweep of port 3072 from the IP xx.xx.xxx.xx and inform me of the results
(account cancelled, user warned, etc).  I will require this information in
order to close the ticket on this activity.  I have attached a portion of
the log details as evidence.  All times are EDT (GMT -4).

(NOTE: This is an automated email response to the incoming scan/attack.)

18:53:39  xx.xx.xxx.xx    0.0.0.0        [TCP-SWEEP]
(total=19,dp=3072,min=213.244.176.12,max=212.1.188.120,May03-17:34:49,May03-
17:43:38) (USI-amsxaid01)
18:53:39  xx.xx.xxx.xx    0.0.0.0        [TCP-SWEEP]
(total=23,dp=1024,min=212.1.191.8,max=212.1.187.114,May03-17:35:14,May03-17:
43:40) (USI-amsxaid01) "

*i replace the ip with " x "*

Answer (score 1):

This is them informing you that the IP address listed in the notice was discovered to be performing port-scanning on port TCP/3072. Once you have identified what is responsible for this suspicious behavior, please notify them so they can close their security ticket.